# SSRS: Chart x-axis should show until yesterday date

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I build a chart in SSRS. This chart shows me in the x-axis the date. The report is sent every morning the problem is the chart shows the today date too. I would like to have only the date until the day before. 
[image]

my query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select intervaldate as Date,

SUM(GoodUnits) As GoodUnits,
SUM(NetUnits) As NetUnits,
    SUM(GoodUnits)  /
    NULLIF(SUM(NetUnits) , 0.0)* 100 As Value

    from Count inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.id
    where IntervalDate >= getdate()-60
    and tsystem.Name in ('111') 
    group by intervaldate
    ) as s
```

How can I show only the days before. But I will not exclude the today date. The today date and value should show me the chart tomorrow.
I hope its understandable.

Comment: What is value of IntervalDate? Today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `DATEADD`, should be something like:

```
where dateadd(day, -1, IntervalDate) >= getdate()-60
```

Comment: I did used this expression: `IntervalDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE())-60,0)
 AND IntervalDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)`